# Как в PHPStorm 10 отключить квадратик при выделении строки?

Tags: phpstorm

Когда хочешь выделить ИМЕННО ЧАСТЬ СТРОКИ и скопировать, иногда шторм зачем-то пытается перетащить эту строку куда-то ... то есть выделяешь... ещё не успел скопировать, а он уже выводит справа над курсором квадратик или снизу под курсором ... который 100лет бы мне не нужен был и приходится кликать на пустое место чтобы он пропал и снова выделять эту строку ...

Если кто знает, подскажите, в настройках пытался найти, но так и не нашёл где это "перетаскивание" отключить.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, скриншот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл как отключить:

> Settings->Editor->General -> снять галочку с "Enable Drag'n'Drop" functionality in editor

Может кому тоже пригодится.